# Looking for a book/novel with a girl who is transported to a world with only animal type humans

Tags: story-identification

I am currently searching for a book (could also be a web or light novel). I read the story about a year ago.
Its about a girl who got transported to another world or perhaps the future. There she discovers that humans have gone extinct and the animals have developed human like characteristics.

She picks up a leopard cub who is injured. She meets a deer who promises her to bring her to a turtle who might know how she can go back. The cub turns out to be the chief of the leopard tribe and he was just small because he was injured. He can transform into a very human like body. As if she was his possession he takes her back to his tribe and tries to quite forcefully “mate” with her. She tries to run away but fails every time. I think in the end they fall in love and even have a child but I am not sure about that part.

I don‘t remember more.

Comment: You read it about a year ago but do you remember when it would have been made? Also, did you read that in English, if so was it a translation and if not, in what language was it?

Comment: I sadly don‘t remember the time it was made. I read it in german but I believe the author had an english sounding name.

Answer (score 3):

***[Gentle Beast](https://www.novelupdates.com/series/gentle-beast/?pg=6#myTable)*** (2016) by Feng He You Yue.

> A girl crossed over to a different world, running into a small wounded animal.
>
> She thought it was completely harmless. She never expected that once he grew up, it would be this world’s most ferocious beast.

It's this one if there are still people looking. I came across this question while I was looking for the novel; I hope this can help some people.
I think I read it on Webnovel, so I kept looking there without finding it.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by editing it to explain how _Gentle Beast_ matches the story described in the question. Copying and pasting the synopsis from the site you linked to into the answer itself would be useful too, just in case the link goes down at some point. See [this post](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9445/122024) for more tips on how to write a good story ID answer. You might also want to take the [tour], to learn more about the site in general.